# Removing similar letters on a word using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

i just want to ask,whats wrong with my code and why does it say segmentation fault(core dumped)? Im trying to sift all the similar letters and only print the dissimilar ones. Here's my code(with skeleton code from my prof) And here's the original instruction: "to remove all occurrences of c in s and returns the result."

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* clean(char* s,int c);

int main()
{
   clean("banana",'x');
   return 0;
}

char* clean(char* s,int c)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
     if(s[i] != c)
      {
        printf("c",s);
        s[i]++;
      }
   }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use debug toolset. Looks like your `banana` string is not in RAM memory (this is what I think).

Answer (score 0):

Because in

```
s[i]++;
```

`s` refers to `"banana"` (a string literal), and you're trying to modify it. Modifying a string literal has undefined behavior, and on many systems it'll just crash because the compiler places string literals in read-only memory.

With gcc you can use `-Wwrite-strings` to get warnings about code like that.

Answer (score 0):

## The segmentation fault

You get a segmentation fault because the string "banana" is a literal, which means that it is read-only.

In your code, you try to do s[i]++, which increases the value of one of the characters.. Which you can't do, because of it being read-only. without it your code compiled and ran fine.

## The solution

Now to answer your question. You specified the solution should return the result, not print it out, and since the literal is read-only, we need to create a new string. I chose to use malloc so that the size of the new string matches that of the old one, but you can also allocate a fixed buffer.

The following code prints "bnn":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // For strlen
#include <stdlib.h> // For malloc & free

char* clean(char* s, int c);

int main() {
   char* result = clean("banana", 'a');
   printf("%s\n", result);
   free(result); // Everything allocated with malloc must be freed.
   return 0;
}

char* clean(char* s, int c) {
    int length = strlen(s), i = 0, j = 0;
    char* result = malloc(length + 1); // +1 for null terminator.
    memset(result, 0, length + 1);
    for (i; i < length; i++) {
        if (s[i] != c) {
            result[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)